# Create a complete user profile on first startup

Tags: meteor

I would like to create some dummy accounts when I first load my meteor application onto a computer. This is for development purposes. I've got this working however I can't figure out how to add data to the sub-schema.

**DB**

```
  "profile": {
    "firstName": "first",
    "familyName": "last",
    "phone": "041111111",
    "address": {
      "street": "22 Test St",
      "suburb": "Melbourne",
    }
  }
```

**Working version that's missing information**

```
 // user creation
    _.each(users, function(userData) {
      // return id for use in roles assignment below
      var userId = Accounts.createUser({
        email: userData.email,
        password: 'password',
        profile: {
          firstName: userData.firstName,
          familyName: userData.familyName,
          phone: '041111111',
        },
      });
```

**Not working - I would like to add in the users address**

```
   // user creation
    _.each(users, function(userData) {
      // return id for use in roles assignment below
      var userId = Accounts.createUser({
        email: userData.email,
        password: 'Zaq12wsx',
        profile: {
          firstName: userData.firstName,
          familyName: userData.familyName,
          phone: '0416089930',
          address: {
            street: '22 Test St',
            suburb: 'Melbourne'
          }
        },
      });
```

**SimpleSchema**

```
Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    familyName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    address: {
        type: Schema.Address,
        optional: true
    }
});

Schema.Address = new SimpleSchema({
    street: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    suburb: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
});
```

Comment: Did you define any schema for user. using simple collection or collection 2 ?

Comment: Yes I'm using collection2

Comment: Can you please show me that as well.

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks, May I know did you attached Schema.UserProfile to direct meteor.users or did something else ?

Comment: Direct to meteor.user

Comment: Let me know if solution work for you

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, You have design a wrong schema for the users. This is how you can design the schema for the users.

Schema for users

```
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    emails: {
        type: Array,
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$": {
        type: Object
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    }
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
});
```

Schema for user profile

```
Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    familyName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    address: {
        type: Schema.Address,
        optional: true
    }
});
```

Schema for user profile address.

```
Schema.Address = new SimpleSchema({
    street: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    suburb: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
});
```

Then you can add the user schema to your meteor.users like this

`Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);`

You can also define all the schema in single object as like this

```
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    emails: {
        type: Array,
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$": {
        type: Object
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    }
    profile: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true
    },
    'profile.firstName': {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    'profile.familyName': {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    'profile.address': {
        type: Object,
        optional: true
    },
    'profile.address.street': {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    'profile.address.suburb': {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your suggestion `Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);` can you show me how I would use this to add in the street and suburb?